# Getting channels of a team using the Graph API is unreliable

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We are using the below graph endpoint to get all the channels for a specified team.

```
GET /v1.0/teams/{id}/channels?$select=id,displayName,description,membershipType
```

When querying a team with recently added channels, it becomes unreliable. For example, I have a team that had 10 channels and I added 3 more. I get the channels for that team in a loop and sometimes I will get 10 channels, some other time 13 channels, and even some numbers in between. Most queries return the correct number of channels, but I easily get a wrong result within a couple of requests. I have a mix of private and standard channels, I tried with new private and new standard channels and I have the issue either way.

We have no caching whatsoever on out side, we call the endpoint directly. We see in the reponses header (x-ms-ags-diagnostic) that the server instance is sometime different, could it be a caching issue on one of your servers? I still have the issue 24 hours after adding the channels.

We are in the context of a migration so it can be bad since we might not move information and we will not know unless we go check each team once migrated.

Comment: HI @Jean-François I am unable to reproduce the issue. Could you please explain whether you are trying to get list of channels or trying to get info of a particular channel please share more info.

Comment: Hi @Ravindra-MSFT I am trying to get all the channels of a team. I add some channels then I loop and I get all the channels of that team non-stop. I check the number of channels I receive and it is inconsistent. It can take some time before getting a wrong result, but I can always have the issue. I tried on different teams too.

Comment: Could you please confirm, how are you creating channel either manually or using graph api.